# django - can't filter object and transfer to template

Tags: django

I've got a model which I'm trying to filter according to an argument passed in the url, then display the filtered object via a template, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the urls.py:

```
url(r'^courses/(?P<course_code>\w+)/$', views.course, name="course"),
```

Here's the view:

```
from website.models import Course

def course(request, course_code):
    current_course = Course.objects.filter(short_title='course_code')
    template = loader.get_template('website/course.html')
    context = Context({
        'current_course': current_course,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Here's the model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short_title = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    course_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    fee = models.IntegerField()
    places = models.IntegerField()
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    short_description = models.TextField()
    age_low = models.IntegerField()
    age_high = models.IntegerField()
```

And here's the template:

```
{% if current_course %}

    {% for course in current_course %}

        {{ current_course.title }}

    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    <p>Sorry, that course doesn't exist.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And when I load the page /courses/CR1 (the course with short_title="CR1" definitely exists because it renders fine on another template where I'm not filtering but just displaying all the courses), it gives me "Sorry, that course doesn't exist."

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
current_course = Course.objects.filter(short_title='course_code')
```

You're checking for course titles with the exact text 'course_code'. You mean to use the value of the variable `course_code`:

```
current_course = Course.objects.filter(short_title=course_code)
```